# Verschiedene Plurale für unterschiedlich große Mengen

Tags: word-usage, usage, grammatical-number

Es ist ein Unterschied zwischen

> Zwei Auto**s** und tausend Auto**s**

Aber beide haben dieselbe Endung,  es gibt es keine passenden Endungen, z. B.

> Zwei Autos, zehn Autoss, zwanzig Autosz, …, hundert Autoxxx, zweihundert Autoz, tausend AutoC, tausendeinhundert AutoCxxx, eine Million Autofnfkksllslellekdkkdk, …

Gibt es Reste einer unterschiedlichen Pluralbildung in der deutschen Sprache (und Dialekten), wo Pluralisierungen, Paarifizierungen etc angewendet werden? (Siehe Kommentare)

Comment: Warum sollte eine Sprache das unnötig verkompilizieren? Hast Du ein Beispiel in einer anderen Sprache, in der das so gehandhabt wiird?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Das Hebräische, Litauisch oder Polnisch kennen z.B. den Dual (Form für zwei). In bestimmten Formen des Arabischen findet sich z.B. auch der Paukal, eine Form für kleine Mengen.

Comment: Proto-Germanisch und Altgriechisch hatten ebenfalls einen Dual, aber im Verlauf der Sprachentwicklung ist er verlorengegangen.

Comment: Der Dual war Teil der gesamten slavischen Sprachfamilie, ist jedoch in den meisten Fällen heute verschwunden. Man findet noch Reste davon in einigen Wortformen bei Dingen, die gerne paarweise auftreten z.B.  Bulgarisch Hände und Beine. - Zu Pantarei: "Unnötig verkomplizieren" ist falsch herum gedacht. Es gibt in vielen Sprachen "unnötig kompizierte" Dinge. Wozu zum Beispiel brauchen die verdammten indoeuropäischen Sprachen jeweils an die 200 Verben mit unregelmäßiger Formenbildung? Sollen sie sich ein Beispiel am Türkischen nehmen, wo alles wunderbar regelhaft verläuft!

Comment: Wenn man die Frage pingelig auslegt, dann ist sie natürlich selbstbeantwortend: Einen *Plural* kann es nur einen geben, weil ein Plural eine Form ist für *pluribus* (mehrere). Plural ist einfach die Form für Mehrzahl (egal wie viele). Willst du eine eigene Form für Dinge, die zu zweit auftreten, dann heißt dein "Plural": Dual. Und ein solcher ist den Grammatikern dieser Welt ja durchaus bekannt, wenn auch seine praktische Verbreitung am Abnehmen ist.

Comment: Die Antwort auf die Frage "Warum gibt es nicht..." ist dann übrigens: Doch, doch, es gibt. Aber offenbar ist die Unterscheidung zwischen zwei und vielen den Leuten, die heute Sprache verwenden, nicht mehr so wichtig wie es vor 2-3 tausend Jahren mal der Fall gewesen sein kann. Jedenfalls nicht so wichtig, dass man dafür eigene Grammatikelemente aufwendet. Man sagt halt "zwei" + Plural, wenn man zwei meint. Oder kurz: Faulheit.

Comment: Wenn die Pluralmarkierung die Anzahl *exakt* angeben würde statt nur pauschal, dann hätte sie die Funktion einer Kardinalzahl und würde die Funktion der existierenden Zahl wiederholen. Die Funktion von Zahlensystemen ist aber sehr kompliziert und kognitiv aufwendig. Keine Sprache würde sich zwei redundante derart teure Systeme leisten. Deshalb bleibt der Numerus eine pauschale Aussage.

Comment: So speziell wie die Frage gestellt ist, in der es nicht um einen Dual geht, sondern im Prinzip um so viele Endungen wie es Zahlen gibt, kann sie keine wirklich sinnvollen Antworten hervorbringen, außer das es extrem umständlich wäre das zu verwenden. So ein System würde ja sogar die Zahlen selber überflüssig machen.

Comment: Hier ist noch eine Art, wie man an eine Antwort herangehen kann: Wortformenbildung (Morphologie) ist eine Art a) syntaktische Zusammenhänge herzustellen b) Bedeutungen zu modifizieren; hier zum Beispiel "Apfel --> Äpfel". Der Bedeutung "Apfel" wird also ein Bedeutungselement "mehrere davon" hinzugefügt. Wie diese Hinzufügung formal genau läuft, ist beliebig. Es kann auch in einer Form geschehen, die in der Schreibung separiert wird, etwa "Äpfel-mehrere". Oder einfach: "fünf Äpfel". Und genau so machen wir es ja. Andere Sprachen kennen gar keine morphologische Pluralbildung, nur Wortaddition.

Comment: @Javatasse: Schließe nicht von dir auf andere. Dass dir keine vernünftige Antwort einfällt, bedeutet nicht, dass das niemandem gelingen könnte.

Comment: @HubertSchölnast Ich würde die Frage aber nicht so stehenlassen. Nur weil andere Sprachen solche Numeri haben, ist es noch nicht legitim, zu fragen, warum sie das Deutsche nicht hat. Der Frager hat sich kein bisschen Mühe gegeben! Man müsste von älteren Sprachstufen ausgehen und zeigen, was verloren ging. Auch dann würde die Frage wahrscheinlich subjektiv beantwortet und passt sicherlich besser in die Linguistik. Dort finden sich am ehesten Menschen, die wissen, welche Mechanismen ggf. den Dual usw. ersetzt haben.

Comment: @HubertSchölnast Ich könnte zum Beispiel zur Entwicklung des Duals im Griechischen  sehr viel schreiben, aber beim *Warum* würde es subjektiv.

Comment: Das Argument des "unnötig verkomplizieren" sehe ich nicht - Warum sind dann nicht alle Sprachen so "schön unkompliziert" ( ;) ) wie die chinesische, die gar keinen Plural hat?

Comment: @HubertSchölnast Du hast zwar eine lange Antwort geschrieben, aber die Frage nicht wirklich beantwortet. Die Frage war warum es das, was der OP beschreibt, nicht gibt. Das Problem mit der Frage ist auch, dass man sich alle möglichen sprachlichen Konstrukte ausdenken und dann fragen kann warum es das nicht gibt. Die Antwort ist dann immer ziemlich spekulativ.

Comment: The dual has disappeared as a productive form in all the (Germanic) living languages, with loss of the dual occurring in North Frisian dialects only quite recently.[10] In Austro-Bavarian, the old dual pronouns have replaced the standard plural pronouns, for example, accusative enk, you plural (from Proto-Germanic *inkw, *inkwiz). Quelle: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dual_(grammatical_number)

Comment: @Javatasse: Bitte lies die Frage noch einmal. Wo steht hier ein »Warum«? Es ist richtig, dass in der Erstversion der Frage ein *warum* enthalten war, aber Takkat hat die Frage längst editiert und sie besser formuliert. Und zwar hat er das gemacht **8 Stunden vor** deinem Kritik-Kommentar.

Comment: @HubertSchölnast Keine Ahnung, wie ich die Änderung verpasst habe. So ist das natürlich sinnvoller. Ich verstehe auch, dass da ein interessanter Punkt dahinter steckt. Den Dual kannte ich auch. Das Argument, dass man sich alle möglichen Konstrukte ausdenken und dann fragen könnte, warum es diese nicht gibt, ist aber auch berechtigt.

Answer (score 4):

### Kurzantwort:

Verschiedene Pluralformen für verschieden große Mengen gibt es. Allerdings nur in anderen Sprachen, nicht in der deutschen Sprache. Grammatische Numerus-Unterscheidungen sind nämlich gar nicht notwendig. Es gibt sogar Sprachen, in denen die Grammatik nicht mal zwischen Einzahl und Mehrzahl unterscheidet (z.B. Chinesisch, die Sprache mit den meisten Sprechern weltweit.) Die Verwendung von Zahlwörtern und Indefinitpronomen reicht völlig aus.

---

### Im Detail:

---

### Einleitung (Allgemeines zum Plural)

**Wer glaubt, es gäbe nur einen Plural, irrt.**

- Wer sich schon mal gefragt hat, warum in einem Wörterbuch **Wörter** stehen, während der Gelehrte weise **Worte** spricht;
- wer sich schon mal gefragt hat, warum nicht alle **Männer** sondern alle **Mann(en)** an Bord sind;
- wer im Atlas viele **Länder** sieht, aber trotzdem durch die **Lande** zieht, und
- wer sich schon mal darüber gewundert hat, dass der Tuchhändler edle **Tuche** verkauft, während man Kinder in trockene **Tücher** wickelt, ...

... wird schon bemerkt haben, dass manche deutsche Wörter zwei verschiedene Pluralformen haben.  (Noch zwei Beispiele: Manche Frauen haben in ihren BHs keine dicken **Dinge** sondern **Dinger**, und man hat Mutter**male** obwohl es Denk**mäler** gibt.)

Daneben gibt es Wörter, die haben gar keinen Plural. Die **Liebe**, den **Mut** und das **Gewissen** gibt es jeweils nur einmal. Dafür kommen **Leute** und **Ferien** ausschließlich mehrfach vor.

Während es bei den *Leuten* noch sinnvoll sein kann zu fragen, wie viele nun gemeint sind, hat es wenig Sinn zu fragen, wie viele Ferien die kleine Lisa diesen Sommer hat. Gemeint ist es nur genau ein einzelner schulfreier Zeitraum, trotzdem wird dafür ein Pluralbegriff verwendet.

Über den Plural gäbe es noch viel mehr zu sagen (Pluralis majestatis, Krankenschwesternplural, ...), aber die Frage bezog sich auf einen ganz bestimmten Aspekt:

---

### Zur eigentlichen Frage

Verschiedene Pluralformen für verschieden große Mengen gibt es tatsächlich in vielen Sprachen. Es gab sie sogar im Urindogermanischen, von dem das Deutsche abstammt, aber es sind nur Singular und Plural übrig geblieben, andere Formen sind längst ausgestorben, leben aber in anderen Sprachen weiter.

**Singular**

Wenn nur ein Ding gemeint ist, verwendet man in allen Sprachen die Einzahl (Singular). Allerdings kommt es auch vor, dass man mit einem Einzahlbegriff die Gesamtheit vieler Dinge, also eigentlich doch mehrere Dinge bezeichnet:

> **Das Laub** fällt von den Bäumen.
>   Marlene trägt **ihr Haar** heute offen.
>   **Der Pöbel** stürmt den Palast.

**Dual**

Der Dual ist eine Mehrzahlform, die es in einigen slawischen Sprachen gibt (z.B. Tschechisch, Polnisch), aber auch in Sprachen aus anderen Familien, z.B. Litauisch und Hebräisch. Damit bezeichnet man zwei Dinge. Die meisten Sprachen, die einen Dual haben, kennen daneben nur noch den Singular und den Plural.

Beispiel Mazedonisch:

- eine Stunde = еден час *(eden čas)*
- zwei Stunden = два часа *(dva časa)*
- viele Stunden = многу часови *(mnogu časovi)*

<sup>**Anmerkung/Korrektur:** In einem Kommentar wurde ich darauf aufmerksam gemacht, dass Mazedonisch und Bulgarisch zwar keinen Dual mehr haben, aber eine besondere Pluralform, die verwendet wird, wenn etwas gezählt wird. Diese Zählform hat sich aber aus einem Dual entwickelt. Tatsächlich wird auch beispielsweise für »hundert Stunden« die hier als Dual bezeichnete Form verwendet: сто часа *(sto časa).*</sup>

Aber auch das Urindogermanisch hat neben dem Singular und dem Plural auch noch den Dual gekannt. Reste davon haben sich in den Personalpronomen der Bayrischen Dialekte erhalten, zu denen auch die in Österreich gesprochenen Dialekte gehören:

- du, di = du, dich
- és, enk = ihr zwei, euch zwei
- ihr, aich = ihr, euch

**Paral**

Der Paral ist eine Sonderform des Dual. Das ist auch eine Mehrzahlform, die zwei Dinge bezeichnet, aber beim Paral müssen diese beiden Dinge zusammengehören, d.h. sie müssen ein Paar bilden. Man verwendet diese Form also nur, um die beiden Augen eines Menschen zu bezeichnen, oder seine beiden Hände, zwei zusammengehörende Schuhe, aber auch die beiden Menschen, die ein Ehepaar bilden. Der Paral wird nicht verwendet, um zwei Äpfel, zwei Bleistifte oder zwei Menschen, die kein Paar bilden, zu bezeichnen.

Man nimmt an, dass die beiden deutschen Begriffe **»beide«** und **»das Paar«** Reste eines solchen Parals sind.

Die Feststellung, ob eine Sprache einen Dual oder einen Paral verwendet, ist oft nicht einfach, weil es fließende Übergänge gibt. Jedenfalls ist keine Sprache bekannt, die einen Dual und daneben noch einen davon unterscheidbaren Paral verwendet.

**Trial, Quadral**

Sprachforscher haben in einigen Sprache, die von Ureinwohnern Australiens und Ozeaniens gesprochen werden, auch Formen entdeckt, die als *Trial* und *Quadral* bezeichnet werden.

Den Trial verwendet man, wenn man eine kleine Gruppe von mindestens drei Personen bezeichnet, der Quadral wird für kleine Gruppen von mindestens vier Personen verwendet.

Interessant finde ich, dass alle Sprachen, die einen Quadral haben, auch den Trial kennen (Es gibt aber Sprachen mit Trial aber ohne Quadral). Und alle Sprache, die den Trial verwenden, verwenden auch den Dual.

Diese Mehrzahlvarianten sind aber ausschließlich auf Personalpronomen beschränkt, und sie geben auch keine genaue Anzahl an, sondern bezeichnen »drei oder einige wenige mehr« bzw. »vier oder einige wenige mehr«.

Damit sind diese beiden seltenen Formen eigentlich Variantes eines Paukals:

**Paukal**

Diese Mehrzahlform gibt es in der Hocharabsichen Sprache, im irakischen Arabisch und in der amharischen Sprache.

Der Paukal bezeichnet kleine Mengen (etwa 3 bis 10 Stück), bezeichnet die Anzahl aber nicht genauer.

**Distributiv**

Das ist ein grammatischer Numerus, der die Zugehörigkeit mehrerer Dinge zu etwas bezeichnet. Im Deutschen gibt es diesen Numerus nicht, aber man kann die Funktion des Distributiv mit dem Wort *je* (*jeweils*) nachbilden:

> Zu jeder Hand gehören **je** fünf Finger.

Auch die Endung -el in *Viertel*, *Zehntel* usw. wird von manchen als Indiz dafür gewertet, dass es in den Vorläufersprachen des Deutschen einen Distributiv gegeben haben könnte.

Auch Latein enthält Reste des Distributiv. Es gibt ihn aber auch in lebenden Sprachen, z.B. in Turksprachen (z.B. Türkisch, Uigurisch) aber auch in Mongolisch.

**Plural**

Das ist der Überbegriff für alle Mehrzahlformen. In Sprachen, die eine der oben genannten besonderen Pluralformen haben, wird damit aber auch jene Mehrzahlform bezeichnet, die große Mengen beschreibt.

---

### Zahlwörter

Es gibt aber auch Sprachen, die gar keine grammatische Pluralform kennen. Dazu gehört auch die Sprache mit den weltweit meisten Sprechern: Mandarin (Chinesisch). Aber auch Japanisch und viele andere Sprachen aus den Ostasiatischen Raum kennen keinen grammatischen Unterschied zwischen Singular und Plural. Die grammatischen Formen für *»Buch«* und *»Bücher«* sind genau identisch, und das gilt für alle Nomen dieser Sprachen.

Wie wird in solchen Sprachen zwischen einem Buch und mehreren Büchern unterschieden? Die Antwort:

- Entweder gar nicht (wenn es keinen zwingenden Grund für eine Unterscheidung gibt)
- Oder mit einem Zahlwort (zwei, sieben) oder Indefinitpronomen (einige, viele)

Die erste Möglichkeit mag auf uns befremdlich wirken, denn sie wirkt auch auf die Mentalität der Sprecher ein. Aber die zweite Möglichkeit gibt es meines Wissens in allen Sprachen, wobei es aber auch Sprachen gibt, in denen man nicht mal bis drei zählen kann, weil es dort außer *»eins«, »zwei«* und *»viele«* tatsächlich keine weiteren Zahlwörter gibt.

Zahlwörter sich auch eine viel einfachere Möglichkeit, die Mächtigkeit von Mengen auszudrücken als grammatische Endungen, die man an Wörter anfügen muss.

Denn: Wenn man für jede Größe eine eigene Endung verwenden will, braucht man so viele Endungen wie es Zahlen gibt. Da muss man sich dann irgendeine Systematik in Form gestaffelter Gruppierungen überlegen, indem man z.B. die Endungen für die Zahlen von 0 bis 9 in variierter Form als Endungen für 10, 20 usw. verwendet und mit den ursprünglichen Endungen kombiniert, um z.B. eine Endung für 57 Stück zu erhalten. Aber was man dann als Endung erhält, ist dann in Wahrheit nichts weiter als ein Zahlwort, dass dann eben nicht als eigenständiges Wort im Satz steht, sondern als Suffix am Hintern eines Nomens klebt. Ein Zahlwort ist es trotzdem.

**Noch etwas ist in Erwägung zu ziehen:**

Jede Sprache, die es je gegeben hat, gibt oder geben wird, enthält nur Begriffe, über die die Menschen reden, und enthält nur solche grammatischen Konstruktionen, die im Alltag sinnvoll sind und tatsächlich verwendet werden.

Wenn sich Menschen in einer bestimmten Gesellschaft nie Gedanken über die Vergangenheit oder Zukunft machen, besteht für sie keine Notwendigkeit, solche Konstruktionen in ihren Sprachen mitzuschleppen, oder sie zu erfinden. Solche Sprachen gibt es. Und wenn man dann doch mal über gestern oder morgen reden will, baut man eben die Wörter »gestern« und »morgen« in den Satz ein. (Japanisch ist ein Beispiel für eine Sprache, die nicht nur ohne grammatische Zahlformen, sondern auch völlig ohne grammatischen Zeitformen auskommt.)

Und weil man nur selten über genau 107 Dinge, oder über genau 44 Dinge redet, genügt es vollkommen, diese Mengen mit Zahlwörtern zu bezeichnen anstatt eine komplizierte Grammatik zu erfinden. Eine Unterscheidung auf grammatischer Ebene ist nicht notwendig, und alles was nicht notwendig ist, verliert sich im Lauf der Jahrhunderte oder wird gar nicht erst erfunden.

Comment: Achtung, kleiner Fehler: Litauisch ist keine slawische Sprache.

Comment: Nochmals was: bei Mazedonisch müsste man nochmals nachprüfen, ob часа wirklich Dual ist. Im benachbarten Bulgarisch ist es nämlich (heute!) eine "Zählform". edin lev, dva leva, tri leva, chetiri leva... mnogo levove. (ein, zwei, drei, vier fünt Leva, viele Leva - der Lev ist die Währung dort). Das kommt zwar historisch in der Tat vom Dual, ist es heute aber nicht mehr. Ich würde stark davon ausgehen, dass es im Mazedonischen ähnlich ist. (Ohne dass ich es jetzt positiverweise weiß.)

Comment: Ein Beispiel für eine Sprache, die oft Singular + Zahlwort verwendet, ist das Türkische: *iki hayvan* (zwei Tier) ist in der Regel so gut wie *iki hayvanlar* (zwei Tiere). Ich vermute, der Unterschied ist ein stilistischer.

Comment: Ad Litauisch: Dumm von mir, das werde ich korrigieren. (Die Litauer werden es gar nicht gern hören, wenn man ihre Sprache slawisch nennt). Bei Mazedonisch dürftest du recht haben: Zumindest der Google Übersetzer meint, dass 100 Stunden »сто часа« heißt. Dann ist aber auch der Wikipedia-Eintrag über den Dual zumindest in diesem Punkt falsch.

Comment: Autsch. Teufel mit Beelzebub korrigieren ;)

Comment: Die Antwort geht an der Frage vorbei.

Comment: @tofro: Könntest du bitte etwas expliziter werden?

Comment: Das war ein Scherz und bezog sich auf dein Statement, Wikipedia müsse korrigiert werden, weil Google Translate was anderes übersetzt. Beide sind jetzt nicht grade als unfehlbarer Quell des Wissens bekannt...