# Plural für unterschiedlich große Mengen

Tags: grammatical-number

Ein neuer User hat vor zwei Tagen eine [Frage über Pluralformen](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/44855/verschiedene-plurale-f%C3%BCr-unterschiedlich-gro%C3%9Fe-mengen) gestellt, die - wie ich meine - voreilig geschlossen wurde, und beim darauf folgenden Reopen-Prozess bisher nur 4 der erforderlichen 5 Reopen-Votes erhalten hat.

Dadurch ist es mir nicht möglich, eine Antwort auf diese Frage zu posten. Das möchte ich aber. Daher erzeuge ich diese Dummy-Frage und poste meine Antwort hier.

Ich bitte den Moderator, die verlinkte Frage freizugeben (es fehlt ohnehin nur noch ein einziges Reopen-Voting), meine Antwort von hier zu dieser Frage zu verschieben, und anschließend diese Frage hier zu löschen.

Vollständiges Zitat der verlinkten Frage:

> Es ist ein Unterschied zwischen
>
> Zwei Autos und tausend Autos
>
> Aber beide haben dieselbe Endung.
>
> Warum gibt es keine passenden Endungen, z. B.
>
> Zwei Autos, zehn Autoss, zwanzig Autosz, …, hundert Autoxxx, zweihundert Autoz, tausend AutoC, tausendeinhundert AutoCxxx, eine Million Autofnfkksllslellekdkkdk, …
>
> Und was gibt es in der deutschen Sprache (und Dialekte), wo Pluralisierungen, Paarifizierungen etc angewendet werden? (Siehe Kommentare)

Comment: Für nächstes Mal: es ist für uns weniger aufwändig, wenn Du Dein Flag einfach auf die Deiner Meinung nach zu Unrecht geschlossene Frage setzt, z.B. mit dem Text: *Bitte öffnen, ich möchte eine Antwort schreiben*